# TileBrush for SIlverlight 2?

Tags: silverlight

As you may know, Silverlight does not have the TileBrush found in WPF. Is there a workaround to do tiling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to contributor at [Silverlight forum](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/84987.aspx)

> TileBrush in Silverlight (2 and 3) is only a placeholder class ready for future expansion and for WPF compatibility

A PixelShader workaround is proposed for now, which description you can find [here](http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2009/03/22/Silverlight-30-Tile-Effect-with-a-Pixel-Shader.aspx)

Someone please edit my post! :-)

Comment: Edit your post? Once they add support for it? Heh. Yeah, will someone please edit this post?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would appear that Silverlight does support the TileBrush, as referenced on MSDN:
[System.Windows.Media.TileBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush(VS.95).aspx). It first appears in Silverlight 2.0 Beta 2.

Comment: Silverlight does have a TileBrush ... but it doesn't support tiling as of Silverlight 3. And ... it looks like it is not supported in the Silverlight 4 beta either! Here's to hoping it is supported when Silverlight 4 actually releases.

Comment: ... and it isn't supported in Silverlight 5 either. /sigh